# Why is the raido is unchecked when i refresh browser in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I'm new in React and Nextjs and found a problem that the radio button is checked when routing site to site but when I refresh my page(F5) the button change to an unchecked one.

Does anyone know what is the problem?
Here's my code

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";


export default function InputForm() {
  const [ifsmoke, setIfSmoke] = useState("1");

  const setSmoke = (event) => {
    setIfSmoke(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form className="border border-solid px-5 py-10 rounded-2xl border-black min-w-[600px] bg-white">
        <div className="space-y-12">
          <div className="border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-12">
              <div className="mt-5">
                <div className="mb-3">ifsmoke</div>
                <div className="flex space-x-5">
                  <div className="flex items-center">
                    <input
                      id="smoke"
                      type="radio"
                      value="0"
                      name="ifsmoke"
                      className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-0"
                      checked={ifsmoke == "0"}
                      onChange={setSmoke}
                    />
                    <label
                      htmlFor="smoke"
                      className="ml-2 mb-0.5 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
                    >
                      smoking
                    </label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="flex items-center">
                    <input
                      id="no-smoke"
                      type="radio"
                      value="1"
                      name="ifsmoke"
                      checked={ifsmoke == "1"}
                      className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 focus:ring-0"
                      onChange={setSmoke}
                    />
                    <label
                      htmlFor="no-smoke"
                      className="ml-2 mb-0.5 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
                    >
                      not smoking
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

At first the radio is checked but at the end it turns to unchecked one.